# How i can take multiple int inputs through string builder

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

How i can take multiple (int) inputs through string builder

my code is

```cs
class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        int a = s[0];
        int b = s[1];
        
        Console.WriteLine(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen `StringBuilder` in combination with accepting user input before. It's usually just used for generating strings. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Yeah this seems like an X/Y problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Using a StringBuilder like this is strange.

Comment: i just want to solve a coding problem in better time complexity

Comment: Why you use a stringbuilder at all with a single string from the console? I assume that you also misunderstand what the int-constructor does. It initializes the stringbuilder with the given capacity(length of the string).

Comment: _"i just want to solve a coding problem in better time complexity"_ - I would suggest sticking to the normal ways of doing things until you're more familiar with the language and framework, if I'm honest.

Comment: Really , i don't know about that

Comment: Is your question 1) how to input one or more integer values from the console, or 2) (as you've described it) how to read input using `StringBuilder`?

Comment: "how to input one or more integer values from the console" yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is for building strings. You want the exact opposite. You want to analyze a string and get its parts.

Let's assume that the user is entering something like `12 7`. Then you can get the parts with

```cs
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] parts = input.Split();
```

Now the array should have a length of 2. It contains strings. To do math, you must convert strings into numbers.

```cs
int a = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
int b = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Now you can print

```cs
Console.WriteLine(a + b);
```

---

But you could also expect the user to enter one number at a time and call `ReadLine()` twice.

```cs
Console.Write("Please enter first number: ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
int a = Int32.Parse(s);

Console.Write("Please enter second number: ");
s = Console.ReadLine();
int b = Int32.Parse(s);

Console.WriteLine(a + b);
```

---

For the sake of simplicity, I have omitted validations.

In the first example, you would have to check the length of the string array. In both examples you would have to use the [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) to validate user input. If the input is not like expected you would then have to inform the user about it and ask him to re-enter a correct input.

This adds a lot of complexity but is essential for a robust application; however, for a simple test code or lesson, this can be omitted.

Comment: yeah , can i do same using string bulider

Comment: No. StringBuilder does the opposite. You could re-create the input from the integers like this: `var sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.Append(a).Append(' ').Append(b); string result = sb.ToString();`. Then `result` would be like `input`.

Comment: Btw., you can index a string directly like `input[0]`, you don't need a StringBuilder` for this. But both yield single characters, not numbers. So, you would have to parse the string character by character and convert all the digits that make up a number into an `int`, detect the space or other delimiter etc.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to mention that he should always validate user input. This code throws an exception if the user enters invalid integers, hence use `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

The [constructor method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-text-stringbuilder-ctor(system-int32)) that you are using has this description: `Initializes a new instance of the StringBuilder class using the specified capacity.`

It only means that space is **pre-allocated**, but that space is *not initialized to anything*, and there are no characters magically present in the string builder for you to use. Still that is what you are trying to do with the `s[0]` and `s[1]` code.

Comment: i want to take user input at once like we take , for eg string [] s = Console.ReadLine().split(' '); and then split into two separate integer( or more ) int a = s[0], int b = s[1] , but using string bulider

Comment: @kulwindersingh Why do you want to use `StringBuilder`? What is the obsession with it? It's used for building strings efficiently. It has no relevance to reading user input.